# Elastic APM agent on WebSphere Liberty Configuration to Filter Specific Application only

Tags: kibana, websphere-liberty, elastic-apm

I have successfully Setup an APM Agent in WebSphere Liberty and APM Server successfully receiving logs. below are my configurations. Since there are Several Applications running on WebSphere, APM Server on Kibana Shows data from all the applications. I cannot find an way to filter out the application on APM dashboard provided. I have added the package name of the Application i want to monitor as the `Delastic.apm.application_packages` , but it isn't seems to do the trick. Is there a way to filter out an specific Application to Monitor in APM agent Level or dashboard level ?

```
-javaagent:/path/to/apm/agent/jar/elastic-apm-agent-1.27.0.jar
-Delastic.apm.service_name=somename
-Delastic.apm.application_packages=packagename.of.javaapp
-Delastic.apm.server_url=http://apmserverIp:port
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter out logs in Kibana, it is recommended your WebSphere Liberty logs are in JSON format. The logs can be set to JSON format by setting the following properties in your bootstrap.properties file:

```
com.ibm.ws.logging.message.format=json
com.ibm.ws.logging.message.source=message,trace,accessLog,ffdc,audit
```

Once, the logs are in JSON format, in Kibana, each log entry will be parsed into separate JSON fields, where you can use these fields to further filter your logs. To filter out specific application logs, you can use the `module` field, which is the Logger name from the log record, to match the Logger name of your application. You can also use the `ibm_methodName` or the `ibm_className` fields to filter by the method or class name of your applications.

For more information on the available fields, please refer to the following documentation:
https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.11/json-log-events-list.html
https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.11/log-management.html

For guidance on Analyzing JSON logs with the Elastic Stack:
https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.11/analyzing-logs-elk.html